# Create Qt Builds with Jenkins on Docker

Tags: c++, qt, docker, jenkins, continuous-integration

I'm a newbie with Jenkins and I'm learning as much as I can on how to use it.
I've created a container with Jenkins ver 2.60.1, I've configured it to work with Gitlab and I've installed the JDK Java SE SDK 8u131.
I've tried to create a build for a simple Java project and it seems to work fine.

Now, I'd need to create a build for a Qt Project. To test (and learn) how it works I've create the following Qt Test project:

- Project01

  - App01
  - mathLib
  - TestMathLib

The .pro files are the following:

Project01.pro

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
SUBDIRS += \
        App01 \
        mathLib \
        TestMathLib
```

App01.pro

```
QT += core
QT -= gui
CONFIG += c++11
TARGET = App01
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$OUT_PWD/../mathLib/release/ -lmathLib
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$OUT_PWD/../mathLib/debug/ -lmathLib
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../mathLib
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../mathLib
```

mathLib.pro

```
QT       -= gui
TARGET = mathLib
TEMPLATE = lib
DEFINES += MATHLIB_LIBRARY
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
SOURCES += mathlib.cpp
HEADERS += mathlib.h\
        mathlib_global.h
unix {
    target.path = /usr/lib
    INSTALLS += target
}
```

TestMathLib.pro

```
QT       += testlib
QT       -= gui
TARGET = tst_testmathlibtest
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle
TEMPLATE = app
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
SOURCES += tst_testmathlibtest.cpp
DEFINES += SRCDIR=\\\"$$PWD/\\\"
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$OUT_PWD/../mathLib/release/ -lmathLib
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$OUT_PWD/../mathLib/debug/ -lmathLib
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../mathLib
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../mathLib
```

This project is stored into a Gitlab repository. What I'd like to do is to crate a build on Jenkins in order to perform the test and compile both the library and the application App01.

I've looked for books, tutorials, articles but I didn't find anythig.
Can someone suggests a good starting point to learn to how to do that?

Thanks in advance for your help!

**Update**

What I want is to:

- Pull changes from Git's repository
- Compile App01
- Compile mathLib
- perform TestMathLib
- final report about tests and compiling

I don't know how to create the build to do that.

Comment: What are the problems you are encountering ? What are you trying to do with jenkins exactly ? If you just want to build the projects a simple automated bash script that does a git pull & qmake & make should be enough... you need to be more specific

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've updated my question